# Develop an ALV-alike Web Dynpro Component

Tags: abap, webdynpro

Is there a way to develop an ALV-alike Web Dynpro component? If yes can someone show me a link, an article or Google search keywords about how-to?

[update] Thank you 4 ur replies. But **I am asking how to develop my own alv, not how to use ALV.**

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you won't find any how-to develop an ALV-like Web Dynpro component, but you can always check the code of standard WD List Viewer at SALV_WD_TABLE component.

You may want to check the `customcontroller` interface methods to get an overview of how the table data arrives for the component, and after that check the dynamic table creation.

Answer (score 1):

SAP provided ALV for web dynpro abap.  Here is the first link I've found:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/80a3de18-ee00-2d10-bfb3-946d7e00fd91

Answer (score 1):

Use the official SAP List Viewer component which is documented [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_smehp1/helpdata/en/74/fd4142646ab46be10000000a155106/frameset.htm).